# Service won't start

Tags: c#, c++, windows-services, visual-studio-2005, procmon

I have a windows service (c++ that involves some C# code).
At production I have a machine with working service, and another that doesn't - immediately stops with this Error 1053..

I compared the procmon of both and saw that before I get the "Thread Exit" Operation it tries to "Load Image" - and the succuss machine - just keep starting...

```
100842  6:07:26.3394767 PM  MyService.exe   3848    Load Image  C:\Windows\winsxs\x86_microsoft.vc80.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_8.0.50727.6195_none_d09154e044272b9a\msvcm80.dll  SUCCESS Image Base: 0x67a50000, Image Size: 0x7d000
100843  6:07:26.3399390 PM  MyService.exe   3848    Thread Exit     SUCCESS Thread ID: 4372, User Time: 0.0000000, Kernel Time: 0.3281250
```

Do you have an idea how to work it from here?

Comment: Please write some code of your service so that we can understand about what it does.

Comment: Could be any number of things... missing library, incorrect bitness (64-bit on 32-bit OS), incorrect library version (new sdk/platform-toolkit on old OS), etc.  You'll need to drill down some more.  Start with just trying to run the executable stand-alone (instead of as a service) and see if the OS gives you more information.

Comment: Thanks @Mark, shouldn't I see any errors in procmon on those use cases

Answer (score 0):

What did solved my issue was reinstall the patch of the subsystem...